# Athena row_number function using in combination with where or count

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, aggregate-functions, amazon-athena

Bit of a newbie here and struggling to get to grips with what should be rudimentary tasks.

I have a simple table with products, many of which have multiple colours. I want to know how many products have more than three colours.

I started with something like the below:

```
SELECT product_colour, 
       product_id,
       row_number() over (partition by product_colour) AS row_num
FROM table
WHERE row_num > 3
ORDER BY product_id
```

The above did not work, because of an outer/inner logic in SQL, Googled it earlier, so misinterpretation is likely.

I attempted this, having followed a tutorial.

```
SELECT rn,
       product_colour,
       product_id,
FROM 
(
  SELECT row_number() over (partition by product_colour ORDER BY product_colour) AS rn,
         product_colour,
         product_id,
  FROM table
) AS t
HAVING COUNT(t.rn) > 3
```

No matter what combinations of syntax "stuff" I try in the vein hope of getting past this error message "'"rn"' must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause". I simply cannot do it.

Having been inspired by the first responder, I have managed to get the closest yet, however, this query no longer returns any error messages, just an empty table.

```
SELECT product_colour,
       t.rn,
       product_id,
FROM 
(
  SELECT row_number() over (partition by product_colour) AS rn,
         product_colour,
         product_id
  FROM table
) AS t
GROUP BY product_colour, product_id, t.rn
HAVING COUNT(t.rn) > 3
ORDER BY product_colour, t.rn
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the list of products that have 3 colours or more, no need for window functions, you can just use aggregation:

```
select product_id
from mytable
group by product_id
having count(distinct product_colour) >= 3
```

If you want to know *how many* products have more 3 colours or more, then you can add another level of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select 1
    from mytable
    group by product_id
    having count(distinct product_colour) >= 3
) t
```

Note: if `(product_id, product_colour)` types are unique in your table, there is no need for `distinct`.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Regrettably neither of those work. :s When I use group by in isolation I receive the following error (Left side of logical expression must evaluate to a boolean (actual: varchar))  and when I tried HAVING I receive this one (must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause). It is rather frustrating as no matter where I turn, I get some variation of the aggregate expression error.

Comment: @NotAVeryGoodDeveloper: the query I provided you with can not possibly generate these error messages. Please run the queries exactly as provided, they will produce the described results...

Comment: Thank you it worked, I very much appreciate your help.